# C# Xml.Linq collection with one item returns "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" using .ToList()

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a `List<XElement>` with a number of XML elements. When I use the `Where()` method, I manage to find the one item successfully.
Using `First()` returns that item successfully, and if I use `Any()` it returns true. However if I use `Count()` or `ToList()` it returns `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Many thanks in advance.

```
    //Elements:
    <meta name="ncc:sidebars" content="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" />
    <meta name="ncc:setInfo" content="1 of 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" />
    <meta name="ncc:tocItems" content="12" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" />
    <meta name="ncc:totalTime" content="8:02:54" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" />
    <!-- another 30 other elements... -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" />

public static List<XElement> GetElements(this List<XElement> els, String nameTag)
{
    var elementsFound = els.Where(e => e.Attribute("name").Value.ToLower() == "ncc:totaltime");
    if (elementsFound.Any())
        return elementsFound.ToList();
    else
        throw new Exception("Some text");
}
```

Comment: Please provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Could it be that your XML contains an element with an empty Name attribute, perhaps?

Comment: i guess your `e.Attribute("name")` returns _null_ somewhere. so `Value.ToLower` throws Exception.

Comment: Thanks everyone. You're so quick at replying, by the time I updated the post with content, you'd answered!
I updated the code and added the elements. When I looked at the last element, I immediately realised my error based on the help you good folk provided here. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one or more of your XElement objects do not have a attribute named "name". All your LINQ queries ("where" in this case) will be only executed if you actually use the result.

Answer (score 2):

this should work:

```
var elementsFound = els.Where(e => e.Attribute("name") != null && e.Attribute("name").Value.ToLower() == nameTag);
if (elementsFound.Any())
    return elementsFound.ToList();
else
    throw new Exception("Some text");
```

Answer (score 0):

There exists an item in your list which has an attribute which returns `null`. **It is not the first one.** `.Any()` and `First()` will both loop just over the Enumerable until the first element is found which fulfills the condition.

`ToList()` will loop over all elements --> one Attribute returns `null` and the call of the `.ToLower` instance method will result in a `NullReferenceException`